# Use of sequences like "In modern's US"

Tags: idioms, word-usage

Is it correct to use possessive case for referring to the time in consideration, like in

- in today's US
- in modern's US
- in last century's England

etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possessives in English can generally only be used to modify **nouns** (strictly speaking, *noun phrases*).   In your examples, two are nouns but one is not:

- in today's US = *in the US of today* (OK)
- in modern's US = **in the US of modern* (not OK)
- in last century's England = *in the England of the last century* (OK, but note we need to add the definite article)

Comment: @tchrist It's why I said "generally" - although to be strict, in English the possessive 's actually modifies **noun phrases**. e.g. My mother-in-law's house; the King of England's wig.

Comment: For _modern_, one could say: _in the modern-day US..._

Comment: @J.R. It's interesting to me that *the* is inserted, whereas one might say "*in modern-day Syria*" without an article. Is this because we have *the* United States, or is some other rule in play?

Comment: @Zairja: Great question; I would probably say "in modern-day America" without the article, too. At any rate, I don't think the article is required (I just found this in a Google book search: _"Nonetheless, racial disparities persist at the highest level of educational attainment in modern-day US."_), but I probably inserted it for the reason you surmised.